# Python define class functions in seperate py file

Tags: python, class, prototype, forward-declaration

I am working on a project that deals with data analysis. In order to simplify the process of finding and modifying functions, I have decided to put functions of a similar purposes in different py files. The issue comes in when functions in one py file require functions from another to work. I think I can solve the issue by working with a class. To demonstrate the solution I am trying to implement, I have three files:

a.py

```
def a1(self):
    self.var=3

def a2(self):
    self.b1(4)
```

b.py

```
def b1(self, x):
    self.var=x

def b2(self):
    self.a1()
```

testClass.py

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=0

    from b import *
    from a import *

a=test()
print a.var
a.a1()
print a.var

a.a2()
print a.var

a.b2()
print a.var
```

This does do what I want but Python is unhappy with me for importing these 2 py files in this fashion. In C++ I could just prototype my functions, forward declaration, and then place their definitions in another file and have no issues. What is the proper way to define functions for a class in a py file that the class definition is not in?

Comment: What do you mean "is unhappy with me"?  Are you getting an error or warning?

Comment: The terminal response that I get for both imports is: "SyntaxWarning: import * only allowed at module level"

Comment: Explicitly name the items you wish to import. `from a import a1, a2`

Comment: just because you can doesn't mean you should. The way you want is very un-pythonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mix-in classes:

```
# In a.py
class A(object):
    def a1(self):
        self.var=3

    def a2(self):
        self.b1(4)

# In b.py
class B(object):
    def b1(self, x):
        self.var=x

    def b2(self):
        self.a1()


# In testclass.py
class Test(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=0
```

Comment: How do execute b2() from within the Test class? Right now I just have b2() and it says "NameError: global name 'b2' is not defined."

Comment: You need an instance of the `Test` class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need classes, you simply need to re-think the responsibility of your functions. In general, any case where you have `A` depends on `B` and `B` depends on `A` you're confused.

What you typically want to have is:

- `C` depends on `A` and `B`
- `A` depends on `B`, or vice versa

An example, perhaps you have a module for fetching and parsing your data, and another for processing it. So you might have `data` and `processing`. You could have something like this:

## A -> B style

**processing.py**

```
import data


def process_something():
    something = data.get_something()
    for thing in something:
        print('This is a thing: {}'.format(thing))


def process_something_else():
    something_else = data.get_something_else()
    for thing in something_else:
        print('This is something else: {}'.format(thing))
```

** data.py **

```
def get_something():
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        return f.readlines()


def get_something_else():
    with open('another.txt') as f:
        return f.readlines()
```

You'll notice that the functions in `processing` only depend on the functions in `data`, and not the other way around. You wouldn't want to re-arrange this so you had `process_something` and `get_something` in one file, and `process_something_else` and `get_something_else` in another file.

Alternatively, you could make `processing` more agnostic.

## C -> A and C -> B style

**your_program.py**

```
import data
import processing


processing.process_something(data.get_something())
processing.process_something_else(data.get_something_else())
```

**processing.py**

```
def process_something(something):
    for thing in something:
        print('This is a thing: {}'.format(thing))

def process_something_else(something):
    for thing in something:
        print('This is something else: {}'.format(thing))
```

And **data.py** would look the same

Answer (score 0):

1. To avoid confusion, in `a.py` and `b.py`, rename your implementation functions `a1_impl`, `a2_impl`, ... (or some other consistent naming convention).
2. Update the code:

   ```
   from b import *
   from a import *

   class test(object):
       a1 = a1_impl   # and however many others you need
       b1 = b1_impl

       def __init__(self):
           self.var=0
   ```

Tested on Python 2.7.10.

The assignment statements in the `class` are creating class attributes, which will be copied into each instance.  The attributes happen to be functions having the correct signature, so they can be called as member functions of your class instances.